# CSS grid with data grouped by rows

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid

I've been giving `display: grid` a test drive for the last few hours and haven't found a working example of how to keep your data grouped by rows (which seems like a very common use-case). I'm trying to replace a table layout with a CSS Grid but can't quite hack it.

Consider this HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col1">Short Data</div>
         <div class="col2">Very Much Longer Data</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col1">Short Data</div>
         <div class="col2">Regular Data</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
```

The above CSS will only affect the rows but not lay out the columns. If I nest another grid inside each row then the data points have no relationship and won't expand in unison (until `subgrid`).

There are a few reasons why this matters to me:

1. I would like each row to be a React component which requires a single outer wrapper tag.
2. I'm looping over a data set of unknown length and React requires a `key` on each iteration.
3. I would like to create zebra stripes or hover events that respond on a per row basis.
4. My OCD doesn't like all children living next to each other without some sort of grouping.

Should I just use good-ol tables?

Comment: Frankly CSS-Grid is not intended to replace tables. I'd stick with what works *and is semantically correct*

Answer (score 1):

The [CSS subgrid feature](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Subgrid) is part of *Level 2 of the css grid specs* and does exactly what you require. It allows you to set:

`grid-template-columns: subgrid`

on the group container (i.e. `row`). The group container then uses the same grid as it's parent, including resizing the columns across all group containers.

However, the feature [doesn't have sufficient browser](https://caniuse.com/?search=subgrid) support yet, so we'll have to wait.